# How to get files http address from ftp server in Java?

Tags: http, ftp

My program uploads a picture in the ftp server and I need to get the http address for the picture. How can I do it so it would be dynamic and independent of a specific server?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing whatsoever that says it *has* an HTTP address, and if it does it is totally under the control of the server configuration. There is no defined mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Does not exist any fixed rule that associate an http address from ftp address. And it does not depends on Java.

It's only a configuration problem, whatever language you use; you have to know when you upload a file on a ftp server if that file will be reachable through an HTTP server and what address it will have.

Answer (score 0):

Paths on ftp servers and http server do not correlate. The only solution I could imagine is:

1. Know the "server root path" for both HTTP and FTP server
2. Know the path relative to this root
3. Combine these two to the full path

Nevertheless there is no guarantee that it will work in every case. It relies on the fact that you can establish a manual mapping of the server roots (see EJP's answer).